# Jquery select element outside of .load()

Tags: jquery

So once loading an element:

```
$(document).delegate('.pch', 'click',function(e){
    var thes = $(this);
    var jsload = thes.attr('jsload');
    var jsref = thes.attr('href');
    if(jsload){
        $('#webPage').load(jsload);
        window.history.pushState({}, 'Title', jsref);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It then becomes (impossible?) for me to select an outside element from inside the loaded page.
Let's say we loaded

slideshow.php

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $("#items > div").css('width', $('#webPage').width()-12);
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

This completely works when viewed from the direct url, but as something is appended through `.load()` it simply refuses to work. So my question is: Is there a backwards version of `.delegate()` for example?

**EDIT:** `Button` and `#webPage` are outside `.load()`, when button is pressed `#items > div` is loaded. I want `#items > div` to stretch to the loadable div's width, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Still looking this over, quick FYI tho, `.delegate` is superseded by `.on()` in 1.7+

Comment: Oh I know, I just prefer delegating. :P

Comment: So it only loads the jsload if you click on an element that contains classtype pch?

Comment: Yes ^ that part works perfectly.

Comment: And you are sure the #webpage is being populated with stuff?  Try going into your debugger and inspecting that element.

Comment: It's being populated and fully works. Yet I can't select an element outside of the loaded element

Comment: Oooh, totally missed the question I guess :P  What kind of element is #webpage?  iFrame?

Comment: Hmm... I'm really confused at to what your problem is.  Is it that your click function stops working?  or is it something else?

Comment: He's loading another page into an element called webpage via ajax.  And inside that webpage, he is trying to access an element that is part of the main page. EDIT: Which is fine in most cases, except when using an iFrame.  iFrames give you a completely new 'window' var which has its own set of elements inside it... which is why I guessed that he's using an iFrame.

Comment: This is exactly what I am after. ^

Comment: I hate iframes and framesets. It's just inside a div.

Comment: Did you actually mean ...$('#webPage').width()-12)... or is there really another element named website?

Comment: I literally just corrected that in the example! haha :)

Comment: ok, but that wasn't your issue?

Comment: Sadly not. I just need a way of getting the width to stretch to the loadable divs width without using width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$("#items > div").css('width', $('#webPage').width()-12);
```

to:

```
$("#items > div").css('width', ($('#webPage').width()-12).toString() + 'px');
```

Comment: This changes nothing, it simply won't recognise any outside elements.

Comment: I find this very strange, if it is just a div then it should have full access to everything there already... perhaps more information is needed?

Comment: Also, just making sure, you are wrapping the contents of your slideshow.php file in <script> tags, correct?

Comment: Oh yes, there's probably not any silly mistakes since it worked when not being loaded. Very odd stuff.

Comment: Try $("#items > div").each(function() {$(this).css('width', $('#webPage').width()-12);});